# How can I reduce the length of the element's border?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My question is really short and clear .. I want a shorter separator than this:

```css
.myclass{
   border-left: 1px solid;
  margin-left: 4px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  height: 3px;
}
```

```html
<span>Age</span><span class="myclass">21</span>
```

This is expected output:

[image]

As you see, I've set `height: 3px` but still the height of that `span` is bigger than `3px`. How can I make that border shorter?

Comment: Did you mean to ask "How can I reduce the height of an element" ?

Comment: @Aziz Yes .. Sorry I don't know English very well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the height of an inline element will have no effect. Add `display: inline-block;` for it to respect `height: 3px;`

Comment: [Great](https://jsfiddle.net/xssmmqk1/1/) .. upvote. But in this case, that border is in the top of element, how can I put it in the center vertically?

Comment: To center: `line-height: 3px;`

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are trying to make the height of the border less, not necessarily reducing the height of the `span` tag (which contains text).

In that case, you can simply use a pseudo element (like `::before`) which you can control more with CSS.

```css
.myclass::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 1px;
  background: #000;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span>Age</span> <span class="myclass">21</span>
```

Notice how the line is 3px high.

Comment: As a note, *pseudo* selector doesn't work on old browsers like IE7.

Comment: Oh, my condolences

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. Just use a | character in the HTML.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mikehomme/31vy9pm6/).

```
<span>Age |</span>
<span class="myclass">21</span>

.myclass {
  padding-left: 4px;
  height: 3px;
}
```

Comment: The height of `|` character is bigger than expected.